Linear response theory for emissions
Is it possible to study emissions via linear response consider an external electromagnetic field emission $A^{\mu}$ studied via the interaction
$$H_{int} = g\int d^4x ~\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi A_{\mu}$$
where I wish to interpret the emission of an external electromagnetic signal via fermions. Is this interpretation sensible?
